# Trying to put a background color over another background color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page to look like this where there is a blue background and then placed on top of that blue background is a white back with a slightly narrower width so that the blue background shows to the sides. I tried putting a div over another div but I'm not getting it right. Not quite sure how to go about this in html/css. Any help would be appreciated! Below is the code I tried.  [Mockup page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFixe.png)

```
<div class="div-0">
    <style>
        div{
            background-color:white;
            width:980px;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</div>

<div class="div-1">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #3b60af;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this where you nest the divs, make one a little smaller than the other, and add `justify-content: center` to the parent div to center the child div

```css
.div-0 {
  background-color: #3b60af;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.div-1 {
background-color:white;
width: 90%;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-0">
 <div class="div-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This did exactly what I needed it to!

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped!

Comment: @EnlightenedTriangle I was playing with the code a bit to make it better.  Try using this code: https://jsfiddle.net/fjpuwm9v/  You might find it better in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Consider padding and multiple background:

```css
body {
  padding:0 11%;
  margin:0;
  min-height:100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#3b60af 0 0) left,
    linear-gradient(#3b60af 0 0) right;
  background-size:10% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
some content here
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: #3b60af;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div.skinny-div {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  div.skinny-div {
    width: 70vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="skinny-div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

inspired by Temani...

```css
    body {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
          #3b60af 10%,
          white 10% 90%,
          #3b60af 90%);
      padding: 0 11%;
    }
```